# How to tune CPU Usage granularity?

Tags: kernel, performance, cpu

It is about **getrusage**.
It works well but precision/granularity is not precise enough.

It does not depend on CPU and its performance. Depends on kernel only.
For actual kernel 4+ **the precision is 3800 μs** (micro seconds). For kernel 3.x it is 10,000 μs

But macos provides much more precise CPU usage. It is about 14 μs (270x more accurate then linux)
Next, on FreeBSD and its linux compatibility layer the getrusage returns updated CPU usage value on each call (e.g. precision is 1.9 microseconds)

Can I tune precision using sysctl or recompiling kernel?

[update] Detailed percentile and Histogram

```
278 increments a second, e.g. 3,597.1 microseconds in average
 1%: 3.000           5%: 19.000         10%: 493.000        20%: 3,500.000      30%: 3,511.000
40%: 3,967.000      50%: 4,002.000      60%: 4,012.000      70%: 4,017.000      80%: 4,447.000
90%: 4,503.000      95%: 4,508.000      99%: 4,567.000

Histogram 'CPU Usage increments (microseconds)'
2.000     ... 399.417      9.7% | @@@@@@@@@@
399.417   ... 796.833      1.1% | @
796.833   ... 1,194.250    0.4% |
1,194.250 ... 1,591.667         |
1,591.667 ... 1,989.083    0.7% |
1,989.083 ... 2,386.500    0.4% |
2,386.500 ... 2,783.917    0.4% |
2,783.917 ... 3,181.333    0.7% |
3,181.333 ... 3,578.750   21.2% | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
3,578.750 ... 3,976.167    5.8% | @@@@@@
3,976.167 ... 4,373.583   38.5% | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
4,373.583 ... 4,771.000   21.2% | @@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@
```

Comment: It sounds as if it might be tick based for linux. Try the low latency, 1000 Hertz, kernel. That might give you 1000 uSec.

Comment: @DougSmythies, But I don't need another kernel with another sheduler/preemption. I want to have getrusage results updated more often than once a 3800 μs.

Comment: Thanks for your update, but I am still not understanding how you are doing your measurements. Regardless, you seem to have several samples at less than 400 uSec.

Comment: @DougSmythies Thanks for the cool demo. My tests doesn't call printf or any code that causes thread context switch on each microsecond.
`git clone https://github.com/devizer/Universe.CpuUsage ~/build/Universe.CpuUsage; 
cd ~/build/Universe.CpuUsage; 
git pull; 
dotnet test -c Release -f net5.0 --filter "Name~Show_Precision_Histogram"`

Answer (score 2):

Could you please provide references and/or method of test that gives you the numbers you posted in your question?

I am able to observe granularity down to the microsecond, but doubt that it is actually accurate to the microsecond.

I wrote a simple program to list user and system time a few times and then only when both change for a few times:

```
/*****************************************************************************
*
* testrusage.c 2023.09.21 Smythies
*       Attempt to observe rusage time granularity.
*       see also: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1486310/how-to-tune-cpu-usage-granularity
*
*****************************************************************************/

#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/times.h>
#include <sys/time.h>
#include <sys/resource.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <time.h>

unsigned long long stamp(void){
   struct timespec tv;

   clock_gettime(CLOCK_MONOTONIC_RAW,&tv);

   return (unsigned long long)tv.tv_sec * 1000000000 + tv.tv_nsec;
} /* endprocedure */

int main(){
   unsigned long long start, now, last;
   long tps;
   long sys_call_counter = 0;
   int i, j;
   long old_sys, old_user, new_sys, new_user;

   struct rusage usage;

   start = stamp();
   last = start;

   for(i = 0; i < 5; i++){
      getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
      sys_call_counter++;
      now = stamp();

      printf("loops: %ld : ", sys_call_counter);
      printf("Elapsed:%llu nS. ", now-start);
      printf("Delta:%llu nS.  : ru :  ", now-last);

      printf("user cpu: %ld uSec. ", usage.ru_utime.tv_usec);
      printf("sys cpu: %ld uSec.\n", usage.ru_stime.tv_usec);

      last = now;
   } /* endfor */
   printf("\n");

   old_sys = usage.ru_stime.tv_usec;
   old_user = usage.ru_utime.tv_usec;

   i = 0;
   while(i < 20){
      getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
      sys_call_counter++;
      new_sys = usage.ru_stime.tv_usec;
      new_user = usage.ru_utime.tv_usec;
      if((old_sys !=  new_sys) && (old_user != new_user)){
         for(j = 0; j < 1; j++){
            now = stamp();

            printf("loops: %ld : ", sys_call_counter);
            printf("Elapsed:%llu nS. ", now-start);
            printf("Delta:%llu nS.  : ru :  ", now-last);

            printf("user old: %ld uSec. ", old_user);
            printf("sys old: %ld uSec. ", old_sys);

            printf("user cpu: %ld uSec. ", new_user);
            printf("sys cpu: %ld uSec.\n", new_sys);

            last = now;

            getrusage(RUSAGE_SELF, &usage);
            sys_call_counter++;
            new_sys = (long) usage.ru_stime.tv_usec;
            new_user = (long) usage.ru_utime.tv_usec;
         } /* endfor */
         old_sys = new_sys;
         old_user = new_user;
         i++;
      } /* endif */
   } /* endwhile */
} /* endprogram */
```

and got this:

```
doug@s19:~/c$ ./testrusage
loops: 1 : Elapsed:2569 nS. Delta:2569 nS.  : ru :  user cpu: 292 uSec. sys cpu: 0 uSec.
loops: 2 : Elapsed:37342 nS. Delta:34773 nS.  : ru :  user cpu: 327 uSec. sys cpu: 0 uSec.
loops: 3 : Elapsed:38697 nS. Delta:1355 nS.  : ru :  user cpu: 329 uSec. sys cpu: 0 uSec.
loops: 4 : Elapsed:39827 nS. Delta:1130 nS.  : ru :  user cpu: 330 uSec. sys cpu: 0 uSec.
loops: 5 : Elapsed:40824 nS. Delta:997 nS.  : ru :  user cpu: 331 uSec. sys cpu: 0 uSec.

loops: 904 : Elapsed:205213 nS. Delta:164389 nS.  : ru :  user old: 331 uSec. sys old: 0 uSec. user cpu: 491 uSec. sys cpu: 3 uSec.
loops: 6486 : Elapsed:1203157 nS. Delta:997944 nS.  : ru :  user old: 491 uSec. sys old: 6 uSec. user cpu: 493 uSec. sys cpu: 1000 uSec.
loops: 9316 : Elapsed:1711772 nS. Delta:508615 nS.  : ru :  user old: 495 uSec. sys old: 1000 uSec. user cpu: 1001 uSec. sys cpu: 1001 uSec.
loops: 9319 : Elapsed:1713784 nS. Delta:2012 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1001 uSec. sys old: 1001 uSec. user cpu: 1002 uSec. sys cpu: 1002 uSec.
loops: 9322 : Elapsed:1715740 nS. Delta:1956 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1002 uSec. sys old: 1002 uSec. user cpu: 1003 uSec. sys cpu: 1003 uSec.
loops: 9325 : Elapsed:1717655 nS. Delta:1915 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1003 uSec. sys old: 1003 uSec. user cpu: 1004 uSec. sys cpu: 1004 uSec.
loops: 9328 : Elapsed:1719611 nS. Delta:1956 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1004 uSec. sys old: 1004 uSec. user cpu: 1005 uSec. sys cpu: 1005 uSec.
loops: 9332 : Elapsed:1721729 nS. Delta:2118 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1005 uSec. sys old: 1005 uSec. user cpu: 1006 uSec. sys cpu: 1006 uSec.
loops: 9335 : Elapsed:1723650 nS. Delta:1921 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1006 uSec. sys old: 1006 uSec. user cpu: 1007 uSec. sys cpu: 1007 uSec.
loops: 9339 : Elapsed:1725728 nS. Delta:2078 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1007 uSec. sys old: 1007 uSec. user cpu: 1008 uSec. sys cpu: 1008 uSec.
loops: 9342 : Elapsed:1727697 nS. Delta:1969 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1008 uSec. sys old: 1008 uSec. user cpu: 1009 uSec. sys cpu: 1009 uSec.
loops: 9346 : Elapsed:1729758 nS. Delta:2061 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1009 uSec. sys old: 1009 uSec. user cpu: 1010 uSec. sys cpu: 1010 uSec.
loops: 9349 : Elapsed:1731665 nS. Delta:1907 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1010 uSec. sys old: 1010 uSec. user cpu: 1011 uSec. sys cpu: 1011 uSec.
loops: 9352 : Elapsed:1733646 nS. Delta:1981 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1011 uSec. sys old: 1011 uSec. user cpu: 1012 uSec. sys cpu: 1012 uSec.
loops: 9356 : Elapsed:1735733 nS. Delta:2087 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1012 uSec. sys old: 1012 uSec. user cpu: 1013 uSec. sys cpu: 1013 uSec.
loops: 9359 : Elapsed:1737668 nS. Delta:1935 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1013 uSec. sys old: 1013 uSec. user cpu: 1014 uSec. sys cpu: 1014 uSec.
loops: 9362 : Elapsed:1739614 nS. Delta:1946 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1014 uSec. sys old: 1014 uSec. user cpu: 1015 uSec. sys cpu: 1015 uSec.
loops: 9366 : Elapsed:1741727 nS. Delta:2113 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1015 uSec. sys old: 1015 uSec. user cpu: 1016 uSec. sys cpu: 1016 uSec.
loops: 9369 : Elapsed:1743624 nS. Delta:1897 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1016 uSec. sys old: 1016 uSec. user cpu: 1017 uSec. sys cpu: 1017 uSec.
loops: 9372 : Elapsed:1745647 nS. Delta:2023 nS.  : ru :  user old: 1017 uSec. sys old: 1017 uSec. user cpu: 1018 uSec. sys cpu: 1018 uSec.
```

Note 1: I do not have old series 4 or 3 kernels. I did this on an 6.X series kernel. (I could do it on a 5.15 series kernel, but didn't.)

Note 2: I am using hardware and a kernel that supports high resolution timers:

```
doug@s19:~/c$ grep CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS /boot/con*
...
/boot/config-5.15.0-79-generic:CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
/boot/config-5.15.0-83-generic:CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
...
/boot/config-5.4.0-162-generic:CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
...
/boot/config-6.6.0-rc2-stock:CONFIG_HIGH_RES_TIMERS=y
```

And those timers can measure to the uSec:

```
doug@s19:~/tmp$ sudo cat /proc/timer_list | grep min_delta_ns
 min_delta_ns:   8001
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
 min_delta_ns:   1000
```

EDIT: I modified my program so as to just print some totals and ran it for 100 million changes to user or sys time as reported by getrusage.
The elapsed time was 100.004 seconds or an average of 1 uSec per change.
The number of calls to getrusage was 529.9 Million times.
The total user time and sys time was 14320833 and 85683415 uSec, and agreed well with what `top` reported during execution.